# Embed segue option is missing in the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, uistoryboardsegue

This seems to be a very simple question, but I can not google an answer. In my storyboard I'm dragging from one view controller to another, a list of segue options is popping up but there's no `Embed` option there which is one I need. I tried Xcode 11 and 10 and it is missing in both. What's wrong? Ho to find it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe `Embed` is only available for a `UIContainerView`... maybe another possibility, but definitely not from one view controller to another.

Comment: 1. UIContainerView? What is this? 2. In my storyboard I have two view controllers connected with a Embed Segue but I cannot do the same

Comment: OK - based on your Storyboard, it looks like your **ChatRoomViewController** has a `UIContainerView` at the bottom, and your **ComposeMessageViewController** is embedded in it.

Comment: I can't find it)))

Comment: Expand the `> View` so you can see all the objects in the controller (and then post that screen cap).

Comment: Please take a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your `UIContainerView`:

[image]

and `ComposeMessageViewController` is ***embedded*** in it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can not find any official reference for UIContainerView. But the storyboard claims it is indeed a UIContainerView.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha - do a google search for `embed segue` ... you'll get lots of results with tutorials, articles, examples, etc of using `UIContainerView`.

Comment: `UIContainerView` doesn't have any documentation because it's really just a `UIView` that Interface Builder sprinkles some magic on to set up the embedding at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`Embed` Segues are used by container views. These are views inside a viewController which loads another view from another viewController

If what you want is to present or push a view controller, you don't have to use an `Embed` segue.

To create a `push` segue or any other, drag click from the first box marked in the image while pressing the `control` key, and place it on the ViewController you want, add an Identifier and use that to configure your VC from `prepareForSegue`

[image]